# Django get_initial method with few fields

Tags: python, django, forms, methods, django-class-based-views

I have django app, and I want to have initial data for date fields

```
promoted_from = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
promoted_to = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

**I need 00:00 in time field.**

In this app I have get_initial method:

```
def get_initial(self):
    initial = super(BasePostEdit, self).get_initial()
    get = self.request.GET
    initial.update(get)
    if initial.get("pub_date", None):
        initial["pub_date"] = datetime.strptime(initial["pub_date"][0], "%d/%m/%Y")

    return initial
```

But I want to have also two another fields `promoted_from` and `promoted_to`. I tried in this way, without success:

```
def get_initial(self):
    initial = super(BasePostEdit, self).get_initial()
    get = self.request.GET
    initial.update(get)
    if initial.get("pub_date", None):
        initial["pub_date"] = datetime.strptime(initial["pub_date"][0], "%d/%m/%Y")

    if initial.get("promoted_from", None):
        initial["promoted_from"] = datetime.strptime(initial["promoted_from"][0], "%d/%m/%Y")

    return initial
```

Please for help/some hint.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do any of this. You can just set a default on the fields themselves:

```
promoted_from = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, default=datetime.datetime.now)
promoted_to = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

**Edit**

If you need to customise the value, use a callable as the default:

```
def midnight_today():
    return datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), datetime.time(0,0))
```

...

```
promoted_from = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, default=midnight_today)
```

Note that it should be a standalone function, not a method of the model.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I think, I need, please check my update: I need 00:00 in time field.